# Enable textbox on click of checkbox in each table row

Tags: javascript, html

I have jquery code. I want same think to do in javascript

```js
//$('.checkme').attr('checked', true);
    $('.checkme').click(function(){
        if($('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled') == true){
            $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', false);
        }else{
            $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>    
        
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sd3" value="mfi_nam9" class="checkme"/></td>  
            <td>First Value </td>
           <td > <input type="text" name="mfi_nam9" class="text required" id="mfi_name" disabled ></td>
        
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sd2[]" value="mfi_nam8"  class="checkme" /></td>
            <td>Second Value </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mfi_nam8" class="text required" id="mfi_name" disabled  >
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use `querySelectorAll` to select all elements having class as `checkme`
  (`'.checkme[type="checkbox"]'`)
- Loop through all the selected elements and attach `change` listener
- Select the parent `tr` element using `this.parentNode.parentNode` and
  select `input` element which is `child` of `tr` element using
  `querySelector`(`'.text[type="text"]'`)
- Manipulate `disabled` property of the `input` element considering
  `checked` property of the `checkbox`

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.checkme[type="checkbox"]'), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.text[type="text"]').disabled = !this.checked;
  });
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sd3" value="mfi_nam9" class="checkme" />
    </td>
    <td>First Value</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="mfi_nam9" class="text required" id="mfi_name" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sd2[]" value="mfi_nam8" class="checkme" />
    </td>
    <td>Second Value</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="mfi_nam8" class="text required" id="mfi_name" disabled>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thnx, if I want one or more text box in row, and want same functionality also happen when checkbox clicked. I have added new text box as 'class=text1' and added in querySelector but it is not enabling and disabling.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns `array-like` nodeList...Loop the returned elements.. https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fbk86dek/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this following code:
Jquery:

```
$(function(){
        $('.checkme').click(function(){
            if($('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled') == 'disabled'){
            $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', false);
        }else{
            $('input[name='+ $(this).attr('value')+']').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prop for enabling and disabling the input element

```js
$('.checkme').click(function(){
 var element = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]');
        if($(this).is(':checked'))     
      element.prop( "disabled", false );
    else
      element.prop( "disabled", true );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>    

        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sd3" value="mfi_nam9" class="checkme"/></td>  
            <td>First Value </td>
           <td > <input type="text" name="mfi_nam9" class="text required" id="mfi_name" disabled ></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>    

        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sd2[]" value="mfi_nam8" class="checkme" /></td>
            <td>Second Value </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="mfi_nam8" class="text required" id="mfi_name" disabled  >
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```